# Sharing object and controlling thread execution from main thread

Tags: java, concurrency, mutual-exclusion

I am trying to solve quite easy problem. I have a main thread, which draws a frame and another thread(FrameThread) that prepares this frame every time. Both threads should share same MyFrame object. I want to control FrameThread from the main thread, i.e.: MyFrame is ready -> draw it in main thread -> keep FrameThread running. Currently i did following:

```
private class FrameEngine
{
    private boolean isFrameReady = false;
    private MyFrame frame;

    public synchronized void generateFrame()
    {
        while(isFrameReady)
            wait();
        frame = FrameGenerator.nextFrame();
        isFrameReady = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized MyFrame getFrame()
    {
        while(!isFrameReady)   
            wait();
        isFrameReady = false;
        notifyAll();
        return frame;
    }
}
```

After that i create FrameThread:

```
private class FrameThread implements Runnable
{
    private final FrameEngine frame_eng;

    public FrameThread( FrameEngine engine )
    {
        frame_eng = engine;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
            frame_eng.generateFrame();
    }
}
```

And finally main thread:

```
FrameEngine frame_engine = new FrameEngine();
Thread frameThread = new Thread( new FrameThread( frame_engine ) );
frameThread.start();
...
while(true)
{
    ...
    drawFrame( frame_engine.getFrame() ); 
    ...
}
```

So my goal is: FrameThread executes in background and stops right after frame is ready. I am very novice in Java, and i feel there is much better and safer way to achieve it. Could you give me an advice about it? Thank you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are right sir.

Comment: @Kael: your code seems unusual to me -- but I'm no threading expert. Is your program in any way a GUI? Is this a java.awt.Frame? If so, why not use Swing and javax.swing.JFrames? If GUI consider using SwingWorkers. And if you don't get any decent answers soon, consider providing a bit more detail if possible.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: i think i should rename it. This is just pure Java, without additional frameworks.

Comment: @Kael: thanks for that clarification. It always confuses me (and probably others) if folks use class names that already have counterparts in the Java core library, and I recommend folks to try to avoid this when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic producer-consumer problem. I suggest that you avoid using wait() and notify() because they are difficult to get right, even for seasoned developers.

Instead, check out the `BlockingQueue` interface and use the example in the comments as a guide. This seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

If it is required that no more than one frame is generated in advance, then use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a capacity of 1.

I should also mention that in both your example and the BlockingQueue example in the link above, semantics for shutting down the producer and consumer threads are not explained. You will need to add a stopping mechanism to be complete, otherwise your program will not shut down on its own, even after the main thread has died.